# Firebase Authentication using email and google

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase in Android Studio with kotlin.

I want to know whether login account is email-register account or google social account.

As I know, if FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.providerId is "google.com", user used google social login.

And if providerId is "password", user used email register with firebase.

But only I can get "firebase" from providerId.

How can I solve it?

It it is neccessary for making login function.

I can get only "firebase" from providerId.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getproviderid), `getProviderId()` (or just `providerId` for Kotlin) will always return `FirebaseAuthProvider#PROVIDER_ID` (which is equal to `"firebase"`).

If you want to determine which authentication channel was used to get this Firebase ID Token, you need to use `getProviderData()` which contains the `UserInfo` objects returned from the social logins.

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
val hasLinkedGoogleUser = auth.providerData.any{ it.providerId == GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID }
```